# MVC4 MEF Plugin System and strongly typed views

Tags: model-view-controller, plugins, view, mef, strong-typing

I'm developping a MEF-based plugin system, in which every dll file under ~/WebPlugins/ folder which exports interface IPluginInfo is considered as a plugin.

```
public interface IPluginInfo
{
    string Name { get; }
    string Description { get; }
    string AssemblyName { get; }
    string Version { get; }
    PluginType PluginType { get; }
    Guid PluginGuid { get; }
}
```

Besides interface export, every dll exports it's own controllers like this:

```
namespace WebSettings.Controllers
{
    [Export("Groups", typeof(ARMController))]
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
    [ArmAuthorize(Roles = "WebSettings")]
    public class GroupsController : ARMController
....
```

In main project i have an overrided DefaultControllerFactory's CreateController method, which allows to search for needed controllers among MEF exported.

```
public class ARMControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
        {
            IController controller = null;
            try { controller = base.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName); } catch { }

            if (controller == null) controller = PluginManager.GetInstance<ARMController>(controllerName);
            if (controller == null) throw new Exception("Controller not found!");

            return controller;
        }
    }
```

Also, there is an overrided RazorViewEngine view location search paths. It allows MVC to search for views in ~/WebPlugins/Views/ folder.

So, everything seems to be Okay, but no.
It is normal practice when controller-view pair uses some model class to pass data between them. But in case of MEF controller export MVC can't find model class, which located in same dll from which controller is exported. And, of cource, view compilation fails on that stage and MVC returns an YSOD in which it complains that can't find model's namespace.

The first idea was to export model classes too, but I can't find out what to do with that exports.

How to tell MVC to use it?
Is there a known workaround for this problem?

Comment: Check out the following link: http://shazwazza.com/post/Developing-a-plugin-framework-in-ASPNET-with-medium-trust It explains the problem and offers a solution for strongly typed views to a model that exists outside of the bin.

Comment: I saw that article and even tried the solution with setting probing privatePath in web.config. No luck.